# Defining a html element as required input

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

The application I am working with has defined a date picker in a separate html file.  This is the definition of the date-picker:

```
<span class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" ng-model="model" min-date="minimum" 
         is-open="opened" datepicker-options="datepickerOptions" date-disabled="notused" close-text="Close"/>
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
  </span>
</span>
```

This date-picker is used in several places throughout the application.  Some of the instances are required, some are not.
There are css classes that are used to show when an input is required and valid.  The definitions are for `input` and `select`.  This is the css classes:

```
input.requiredField.ng-valid {
  border: 1px solid #449d44;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #449d44;
}

input.requiredField.ng-invalid {
  border: 1px solid #A33441;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #A33441;
}
select.requiredField.ng-invalid {
  border: 1px solid #A33441;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #A33441;
}

select.requiredField.ng-valid {
  border: 1px solid #449d44;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #449d44;
}
```

I am having trouble adding the css to the date-picker to show that the date-picker is required.

This is the 2 date-pickers that I am using:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
   <label id="startDateLabel" style="margin: 25px;">Start Date:</label>
   <date-picker id="startDatePicker" type="text" model="updateWrhParams.startDate" ng-required="updateWrhParams.startDateRequired"
style="margin-top: 25px; margin-bottom: 25px; margin-right: 70px; float: right;">
</date-picker>      
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">                  
  <label id="endDateLabel"  style="margin: 25px;">End Date:</label>
  <date-picker id="endDatePicker" type="text" model="updateWrhParams.endDate"  ng-required="updateWrhParams.endDateRequired"
style="margin-top: 25px; margin-bottom: 25px; margin-right: 70px; float: right;">
</date-picker>
</div>
</div>

<button type="button" id="updateBtnWrh" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-left: 80%; background-color: #41a334;" ng-disabled="updateWarehouseForm.$invalid" ng-click="updateWrh()">Update</button>
```

I set ng-required values to true in the controller:

```
$scope.updateWrhParams.startDateRequired = true;
$scope.updateWrhParams.endDateRequired = true;
```

How can I add the define the date-picker with a .css class as required?
Also, when the input is empty, the date-picker is invalid?
When a enter an invalid date, the button becomes correctly disabled.  But initially, the button is enabled.

I am using angularjs 1.4.

Comment: can you create plunkr and show your problem?.. so that it will be easy to solve it..

Comment: how to create a plunkr?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that the css is loading correctly. Everything seems to be good with your code. Only missing the ng-class directive for this to work. [reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

This will add the required classes when the expression is `true`

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.startDateRequired = true;
  $scope.endDateRequired = false;
  $scope.model = {};
});
```

```css
input.requiredField.ng-valid {
  border: 1px solid #449d44;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #449d44;
}

input.requiredField.ng-invalid {
  border: 1px solid #A33441;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #A33441;
}

select.requiredField.ng-invalid {
  border: 1px solid #A33441;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #A33441;
}

select.requiredField.ng-valid {
  border: 1px solid #449d44;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #449d44;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app='myApp'>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <form>
 
  <input 
  type="text"
  ng-model="model.start"
  class="form-control" ng-required="startDateRequired"
  ng-class="startDateRequired == true ? 'requiredField':''"
  />
  
   <input 
  type="text"  ng-model="model.end"
  class="form-control"  ng-required="endDateRequired"
  ng-class="endDateRequired == true ? 'requiredField':''"
  />
</form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Let us know.

Comment: It is still not working with my html.  You are using the `input` element.  I need to use the `date-picker` directive as shown in the first code display.  I tried adding your suggestion to the date-picker directive and the page where I implement the date-picker and it still will not but a red box around the input area.

Comment: @GloriaSantin the actual directive you need to use/take into account is the `ngClass` and how it's used. by evaluating the expression `startDateRequired` ngClass will append the proper css class.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that.  I will look at it again early next week. I was pull off of this project for another.